# How can I "checker deselect" vertices of a uv sphere correctly?

Tags: mesh

I'd like to select every second vertex of an UV sphere using "checker deselect"

I tried it like that:

1. select all vertices with "A"
2. Chose "checker deselect" from menu

But the result looks like that:

[image]

Only the area within the 3 meridians in the middle look like how I expected.
For the the rest of the sphere whole latitudes are selected, what I don't wanted !?

Some ideas ?

Comment: As a side note to ChameleonScales' answer, you could instead use a "round cube" instead of an icosphere.  To make a round cube, add a cube, go into edit mode and subdivide it as many times as necessary.  Then in the Mesh menu do Transform -> To Sphere (shift alt s) and drag until it's spherical. (Use the window at the bottom left, in the Toolbar to adjust the number to 1.) Now when you do the Checker Deselect it does what you want.

Comment: I take that back; when you do a face select instead of vertex select it doesn't do it quite right where the edges of the cube were.  But it looks like it's working with vertex select.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to deselect the pole vertices before doing Checker Deselect :

[image]

[image]

Comment: cool , that's it, thank you !!
Is there an easy explanation for it

Comment: well the uv sphere is made of a clean grid of quads except on the poles which add triangles and join everything. The Checker Deselect needs a checker-like grid to work properly. If that worked for you, don't forget to accept the answer.